# Организация кода для приватного и публичного чатов с помощью socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Как создать несколько чатов с помощью socket.io в NodeJS? Я создал публичный, а хочу еще приватный , просто не понимаю как сделать несколько соединений к чатам.

Что-то вроде :

```js
var io1 = require('socket.io')(
    httpServer, { transport: ['websocket'] }
);

var io2 = require('socket.io')(
    httpServer, { transport: ['websocket'] }
);

io1.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection by: ' + socket.id);
});

io2.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection by: ' + socket.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно подцеплять пользователя к какой-то приват id.

В случае с чатом - это может быть id комнаты, а для переписки(ЛС) - это может быть некий `dialog_id`.

Это делается методом `join()`:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join(dialog_id);
});

// юзер прикреплен к dialog_id
```

В таком случае пользователи, которые прикреплены к данному `dialog_id`, могут получать ответы от сервера *отдельно* от других пользователей.

Способ ответа сервера по `dialog_id`:

```
io.to(dialog_id).emit('some event');
```

Подробнее можно прочитать в [документации Socket.IO](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).

Comment: Спасибо, мне надо namespace))